# Issue target array (shape) in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, prediction

I am trying to build a model which identifies the dog breed. For this, I am using "Dog Breed Identification" dataset from Kaggle. Everything goes fine until I fit the model.

I am getting this error" ValueError: A target array with shape (32, 120) was passed for an output of shape (None, 20) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output."

and unfortunately I can not find any  info online of how to resolve it.
I am brand new to keras and I will appreciate any guidance or advice.

this is my project in colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1fju0jgi5UktzCnya7AwB8QaM-e6iIQzG

Comment: You have 120 classes in your dataset while your final network shape indicates only 20 classes. Change the last dense layer last Dense layer to 120. Rest should be okay

Comment: thank you @talos1904